# Equivalence of 2 definitions of Differentiability

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $X,Y$ be Banach spaces. I would like to prove the equivalence of the following definitions of differentiability. Let $f:X\to Y$ and $a\in X$

1. There is a map $\Delta : X \to L(X,Y)$ continuous at $a$, s.t.
   $$f(x)=f(a)+\Delta(x)(x-a)$$
2. There is a map $D_af\in L(X,Y)$ s.t.

$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)-D_af(x-a)}{\|x-a\|_X}=0$$

The implication 1 => 2 is easy by picking $D_af=\Delta(a)$.
Im however stuck on the other direction, do I have to assume that $X,Y$ are finite dimensional?

1 => 2: Assume 1 holds, then

$$\begin{align*}\frac{f(x)-f(a)-\Delta(a)(x-a)}{\|x-a\|_X}&=\frac{\Delta(x)(x-a)-\Delta(a)(x-a)}{\|x-a\|_x}\\
&=[\Delta(x)-\Delta(a)]\left(\frac{x-a}{\|x-a\|_X}\right)\to0\end{align*}$$ since  $\Delta$ is continuous at a.

For 2=>1 I can do the 1-dimensional case. Then the map $D_af$ is just multiplication with the element $f'(a)$. If I let
$$R(x):= \frac{f(x)-f(a)-D_af(x-a)}{x-a}$$
And define the map $\Delta(x)$ to be multiplication with the element $(f'(a) + R(x))$ (for $x\neq a$ and $D_af$ else) everything works out fine.

So I thought the general finite dimensional case should work similar by defining $\Delta(x)$ to be the map given by the Jacobi Matrix of $D_af$ with every entry increased by $R(x):=\frac{\|f(x)-f(a)-D_af(x-a)\|_Y}{\|x-a\|_X}$. This surely gives continuity at $a$ but I don't see how the equality in 1 follows.

For the infinite dimensional case I have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, misread a letter,

Comment: Finite-dimensionality is not needed, I believe. What have you tried for the 2 -> 1 direction?

Comment: @epimorphic I have editet in some thoughts for 2 => 1

Comment: If you understand Spanish, you can read this [paper](http://matematicas.uis.edu.co/~integracion/rint-html/volumen/vol24(2)2006/24II-RCabralesetal.pdf) by Cabrales,Rojas-Medar (2006), teorema 3.2, p. 93.

Comment: It is worth remembering that your question is on the equivalence of Frechet's and Caratheodory's definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a generalization of your approach for the one-dimensional case to all cases, making heavy use of the axiom of choice.

For convenience, set $\eta(x):= f(x) - f(a) - D_a f(x-a)$.
Define $R \colon X \to L(X, Y)$ by choosing at each $x \in X$ an
$R(x) \in L(X, \operatorname{span}\{\eta(x)\}) \subset L(X,Y)$
such that
$R(x)(x-a) = \eta(x)$
and
$$\|\eta(x)\|_Y = \|R(x)\|_{L(X,Y)} \cdot \|x-a\|_X;$$
this is possible due to the Hahn–Banach theorem. Note that $R(a) = 0$. We take $\Delta := D_a f + R$, which satisfies the equality in 1.

By 2 (which is the usual definition of Fréchet differentiability), there is for each $\epsilon > 0$ a $\delta > 0$ such that $\|x-a\|_X < \delta$ implies
$$\|\Delta(x) - \Delta(a)\|_{L(X,Y)} = \|R(x)\|_{L(X,Y)} < \epsilon.$$
This is the continuity of $\Delta$ at $a$. (Note that there is zero guarantee of continuity anywhere else.)

Comment: Thank you. Could you elaborate a little more on the use of the Hahn-Banach theorem. Why can we pick R(x) s.t. this norm equality holds?

Comment: Or asked differently, could I also argue this way? Instead of the Hahn Banach theorem i use Zorn's Lemma to extend $\{(x-a)\}$ to a basis of $X$ and define $R(x)$ on this basis by $R(x)(x-a)=\eta(x)$ and zero on all other basis vectors and the equality follows.

Comment: @Sebastian You would be correct if we were dealing with an orthogonal basis on a Hilbert space. The problem in the Banach / non-orthogonal case is that your method actually fails to bound the norm of the extension. This is because the point of minimal norm of the level sets $[R(x)]^{-1}(y)$ of your extension might not lie in the subspace $\operatorname{span}\{x-a\}$ where the $R(x)$ was defined before extension. You could have a point $x'$ which is closer to the origin than $x-a$ but $R(x)(x') = R(x)(x-a)$, leading to $\|R(x)\| > \|\eta(x)\| / \|x-a\|$ rather than equality.

Comment: Oh, yes, I see.

Comment: @Sebastian In the proof of Hahn–Banach that I know, you extend the functional one basis vector at a time. It turns out there always exists at least one value to which you can map a new basis vector without increasing the norm of extension. That value may or may not be $0$.

Comment: I think I got it. On the 1 dimensional subspace $span(x-a)$ we define a linear functional $F$ by $F(x-a)=1$ and we let $p$ be the sublinear functional $p(z)=\frac{\|z\|}{\|x-a\|}$ then for $v\in span(x-a)$ $F(v)\leq p(v)$ and we can extend $F$ to $F'$ with $F'(v)\leq p(v)$ for all of $v \in X$. Now set $R(x)(z)=F'(z)\eta(x)$ and the result follows.

Comment: Is that correct?

Comment: @Sebastian Seems right to me. Hahn–Banach is usually stated only for linear functionals. But as you can see, it's also applicable to continuous linear maps whose image is one-dimensional.

Comment: Yes, i was a little confused about that, but now it all makes sense. Thanks a lot.